# Magento - template displays correctly once Layouts in Cache Storage is Disabled

Tags: magento, caching, frameworks, themes, magento-1.8

I have created a custom mini-header & mini-footer phtml file that I use within a Magento installation but only on the checkout pages. (These are basically very minimal header/footers with very little content)

```
e.g
IF (any CHECKOUT page) 
    Use mini-header & mini-footer
ELSE
    Use the default header/footer files for that theme.
```

I have a CMS static block called 'Footer Links' that will sometimes seem to override my own 'mini-footer.phtml' - it is inconsistent, sometimes on a checkout page I will see my mini-footer and another times it obvious that the 'Footer Links' static block is appearing (with 15+ html links).

At the moment the only I way I can force Magento to use my custom mini-footer.phtml is to DISABLE the '**Blocks HTML output**' Cache Storage Management within the Magento Admin, however I want to have this option ideally turned on for a live site for extra speed performance.

Can anyone suggest what to do?

Comment: Search your template files for `Mage::getModel(` or `->load(`.  Those are typically signs of a poorly built theme and often cause issues with caching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File this one under Works as Designed, although your question is a little unclear.  Using stateful information within a **cached block** or the template of a **cached block** will lead to one state being added to the cache, and your conditional won't run again until the cache expires the entry.

As for a solution, it's not 100% clear from your question how you've set this up.  You say you have a

```
mini-header.phtml
mini-footer.phtml
```

Then you have some conditional logic, but you don't mention where this conditional logic is.

Then you say you have a CMS static block called Footer Links.

You don't mention how mini-header.phtml or mini-footer.phtml are added to your layout.

You don't mention how you're adding the CMS static block.

All these details will matter if you want to find a solution to your question.

Comment: Thanks I sorted (with some help from other devs in the team) I will try to post a full solution but it was cache related

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue here. After installing a theme extension, I have come to notice that things go haywire when I click on a category:  Static blocks appear in random locations.  To sum it up, I got better results by disabling "Blocks HTML Output" cache.

I am tempted to try to install a different cache implementation.

Comment: There is a dirty fix out for this issue.  https://pagayo.com/blog/magento-192-static-block-problem/

Answer (score 0):

My theme designer mentioned to me that this is a well known bug and that patching would help solve the problem.  Although I was not able to solve the problem with a patch, I was able to solve the problem by upgrading C.E. from 1.9.2.0 to 1.9.2.1